# android: checksum for string

Tags: android

Does anyone know an easy way to generate a checksum for a String on an Android?  I have a NMEA sentence I have generated in a String class and it is ready to be sent, but it needs a checksum to be appended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/zip/CRC32.html

Standard java way for checksums. I guess this should be useful

Comment: Thank-you, but is there some example code for this?  I have a hard time translating the references to something I can use.